# jquery: can't get nested element by tag and change its html

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1aftsyw9/

I have two buttons wrapped in a div. Each div has a custom attribute `value`. I first get an array of all divs with `value = 0` and then try to access the `<button>` in the first div and change the button's `innerHTML` to `Changed`. However it is not working:

```
<div>
  <div value = 0>
    <button>
      Hello
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <br/>
  <div value = 1>
    <button>
      Bye
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var selected = $('div[value = 0]');
alert(selected[0].innerHTML);
var button = selected[0] > $("button");
alert(button.innerHTML);
button.html("Changed");
```

Comment: This is not valid code: `selected[0] > $("button");`

Comment: Also, you don't need `innerHTML` to access an element's children.

Comment: `$('button', 'div[value="0"]')` would select the first button on your markup. https://jsfiddle.net/gwL8v5uj/

Comment: What if I want to use the variable `selected` in selecting a button?

Comment: A `<div>` has no `value` attribute. Set the `value` on the `<button>` or use a `data-*` attribute

Comment: Good point mentioned by @Andreas. `value` is not a valid property/attribute for a `div` element.

Comment: @Andreas, valid or not the value divs do get selected. All I need is to use the `selected[0]` object to select the `<button>` element inside it

Comment: _"valid or not"_ - Invalid markup is a possible source for problems/errors. It might work now but it can break with the next update of a browser. Just fix that problem and use valid markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line `var button = selected[0] > $("button");`

You're trying to use the child selector in the wrong way.
The right way to use a child selector is like this: `$( "div > button" )`

> Read more about Child Selector here:
> https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

The right solution to your problem is to use `.find()` instead.

Here's a working example:

```js
var selected = $('div[value = 0]');
alert(selected[0].innerHTML);
var button = selected.find( "button" );
alert(button[0].innerHTML);
button.html("Changed");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div value = 0>
    <button>
      Hello
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <br/>
  <div value = 1>
    <button>
      Bye
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the difference with `var button = $("button", selected);`? What's the better approach and why?

Comment: @parsecer I didn't really use this approach before, but I think it's good if you want to apply the same property or function on multiple elements. It depends on your usage tho